# Swiper slider проблемы с отображением

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Установил на сайт двойной слайдер `swiper slider`. При загрузке отображается только один слайдер вместо двух, если несколько раз перезагрузить страницу - отображается корректно. Также хочу убрать тач на этом слайдере, прописал свойство `simulateTouch: false`, а оно не работает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться
[ADVANCE AGENT](http://agent.home.highmax.ru/), раздел "Скриншоты программы"

Comment: Добавьте код вашего слайдера и я вам непременно помогу